# Dependency Injection within outputcache filter in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject, outputcache

Is there a way to do dependency injection inside an outputcache attribute where I can check some things in a database before I return the cache or not?

```
[CustomOutputCache(CacheProfile = "Documents")]
        public virtual ActionResult Scoresheets(int? eventId, int? gameId)
        {
```

Comment: It's better to keep attributes passive as described [here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/13/passive-attributes/) and [here](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=98).

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an alternative approach...

I have not tried DI within a custom OutputCache attribute. But if you have tried and if there is no way to hook into the DI container, I would mimic the [OutputCache attribute behavior in an Action Filter](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2008/06/26/Creating-an-ASPNET-MVC-OutputCache-ActionFilterAttribute.aspx) and use the DI within the action filter. You probably know it is [very easy to inject dependencies to the action filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199618/using-unity-to-inject-dependencies-into-a-custom-actionfilter) using a DI container.